# Is there a way to define values or states for object properties in an Ontology?

Tags: state, owl, ontology, relation, object-property

I'm trying to define different states for object properties between OWL classes in my ontology. What already works is creating a new object property every time I'm having a new state for it.

So this would be the way im solving it:

> Concept --- hasConcept --> Concept

Now I want to see all the archived Concepts of a Concept. So whenever I'm archiving one Concept I'm changing the object property from `hasConcept` to the following new object property:

> Concept --- hasArchivedConcept --> Concept

The problem with this solution is that I'll have to create the same `hasArchived*` object property for many other classes in my ontology.

> Concept --- hasTerm --> Term
>
> Concept --- hasArchivedTerm --> Term

and so on.

In order to deny that effort of having to create multiple object properties every time I need a new state, I'm looking for another smooth semantic OWL way to fullfill that requirement.

Comment: Do mean like you had a blue car (initial state) and painted it red (new state), so wish to record triples like: "Car hasColor Red" and "Car hadColor Blue", where "hadColor" is the archive term for "hasColor"?

Comment: Note that you can't formally connect two OWL classes with an object property. If you try this, it will induce punning (i.e. you will be connecting two individuals with the same IRI as your class). This may be fine for you, or you may want to use annotation properties. It's also not all that clear what you're trying to do, what an archived concept it, and what the hasConcept or hasTerm properties mean.

Comment: @PaulBrown thats exactly what im trying to do

Comment: @cmungall i didnt know that you arent allowed to connect two classes with more then one object property. When could i run into trouble with this method? Also, how can I access annotation properties of an object property. Everytime i add an annotation property, it shows up as an axiom, which i cant seem to access via SPARQL.

Comment: @slowmo - it isn't so much that are you aren't allowed, it's more that it isn't possible in OWL-DL. If you try and do it, you actually end up punning and making a link between two individuals with the same IRIs as your classes. See: https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OWL **isn't** the best representation for this due to being limited to binary predicates. You're either trying to represent something is true at a known time, or in a hypothetical or known situation, which in AI is known as a Fluent (see [Situation Calculus](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Situation_calculus)):

```
colour(car, red, time1). % time1 can be substituted for a situation reference
colour(car, blue, time2).
```

So we'd need ternary relations. The solution from Situation Calculus, is to reify the fluent:

```
holds(colour(car, red), situation0).
```

Each predicate is now only arity 2, but OWL doesn't allow a triple as a subject.

The simplest solution for OWL is from [the recommendation for representing n-ary relations in OWL](https://www.w3.org/TR/swbp-n-aryRelations/), use-case 1:

```
colour_at_time(car, _ct1).
colour(_ct1, red).
time(_ct1, t1).
```

There's a disadvantage to such a work-around:  you are sacrificing reasoning and clarity in queries.

There also exists an Ontology based on Situation Theory plus several event based ones with regards to time. Good places for research are: [ODPs](http://ontologydesignpatterns.org/wiki/Submissions:ContentOPs), [Semantic Sensor Network Ontology](https://www.w3.org/TR/vocab-ssn/#SOSAobservedProperty) because of observations, [Prov-O](https://www.w3.org/TR/prov-o/) because changes to documents over time, and BFO v1 for qualities, processes and the now removed object properties.